Подсчитать количество уникальных пользователей за период с помощью promql запроса
Есть метрика логинов пользователей в приложение:
logins{user="userId", xxx="yyy"... }

...
Задача посчитать количество уникальных входов пользователей за период. Если пользователь с уникальным userId заходил за период любое количество раз - считаем +1 уникальный вход за этот период.
...
Пример №1:
Пользователь x заходил в приложение один раз в день 3 дня подряд.
Всего (за 3 дня) - 1 уникальный пользователь.
За 2 дня - 1 уникальный пользователь.
За 1 день - 1 уникальный пользователь.
...
Пример №2:
3 разных пользователя зашли в приложение по очереди (последовательно) через день.
Всего (за 3 дня) - 3 уникальных пользователя.
За 2 дня - 2 уникальных пользователя.
За 1 день - 1 уникальный пользователь.
...
За общий период считаем так:
count(sum by(user) (logins))

Агрегируем по id и считаем получившееся количество.
...
Как посчитать сколько уникальных пользователей было за период в N дней?

Prometheus принципиально не предназначен для того, чтобы записывать метрики каждого отдельного пользователя https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#do-not-overuse-labels

Логика происходящего описанная в вопросе не должна работать, КМК. Ну или инструментация кода сделана даже хуже чем andreymal указал в своём комментаріі. У Вас метрика logins что никогда не истекает?

Задачу удалось решить таким запросом (где N это промежуток, например 1d):
count(sum by(user) (logins))
-
count(sum by(user) (logins) 
==
sum by(user) (logins offset N))

